# Как осуществить поиск по словам

Tags: java

Задача: осуществить поиск по словам.
Например, есть слово strong (это первый массив), а есть armstrong (это второй массив).
Если во втором слове есть первое, то значит выводим первое.

Проблема: начал решать эту задачу через регулярки, но он с таким кодом выводит только "live", хотя как я подразумевал - он первый массив будет сравнивать со вторым.

Ещё для примера:

```
String a[] = new String[]{ "arp", "live", "strong" };
        String b[] = new String[] { "lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong" };
```

Код:

```
public static String[] inArray(String[] array1, String[] array2) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(array1[i]);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(array2[i]);
        while (mat.find()) {
        System.out.println(mat.group());
        }
    }
    return ??;
}
```

Comment: Если вам не важно, как решить задачу(регулярки), то проще пройтись по второму массиву, проверяя на содержание одной в другой методом contains. Если нашли - выводим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените на:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*" + a[i] + ".*");
```

`".*" + a[i] + ".*"` означает, что до и после `a[i]` может быть от 0 до бесконечности любых символов. Вы же ищите только полностью совпадающие с `a[i]`.
И вообще - вы ищете только в равных по индексу(в массиве) словах. Нужно сделать вложенный цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*" + a[i] + ".*");
    for(int c = 0; c < b.length; c++){
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(b[c]);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            System.out.println(mat.group());
        }
    }
}
```